# How to connect mongodb to other devices connected to a MERN application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In college, we had a group project, making a MERN application. It works fine on my laptop, but if any other device connects to the IP address and port number, all that comes up is the client-side React to stuff.

How could I have the data from MongoDB show up on other connected devices?

On my phone, I tried connecting to the port the laptop was using, hoping the phone would also display the information that the laptop did. It did not.